# Editing /etc/hosts causes Apache server block to be missed

Tags: apache2, hosts

In order to fix some email (SPF) issues, I changed my Ubuntu VPS hostname to its FQDN in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`. However, now, when I hit the URL in a browser I get a 404 from Apache instead of triggering the block in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` which would redirect to the `www` version of the site. Typing `www.example.com` still works.

My hosts file now looks like this:

`127.0.0.1 localhost
256.256.256.256 example.com # I am using a real IP and FQDN, obviously`

I don't know enough about it to know why Apache is serving up a 404. It says `The requested URL / cannot be found on this server` and nothing else. Why did editing my `hosts` file cause this?

Comment: I deleted the entry in `/etc/hosts` with the IP and domain and it's still happening - could it actually be `/etc/hostname` that is causing the issue?

Comment: Figured it out - `000-default.conf` is actually enabled and needs to be updated, whereas I never paid it any attention before since everything "just worked".

Comment: Don't put the FQDN in your `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/hostname` - this should just be the locally known hostname for your machine, otherwise a few things will work weirdly. Also, what is in there is not related to your Apache setup or how people on the internet find your machine.

Comment: If I didn't do that then mail sent from that machine was failing SPF because the machine was sending as `mymachinename.local` in mail headers I examined.

Comment: You need to configure the mail hostname in your MTA, eg `myhostname` in postfix.  Set this to a FQDN, or set it to a blank string and set `mydomain` and it'll automatically determine the FQDN.

No need to change `/etc/hostname` or `/etc/hosts` to something non-standard just to try and influence one service because what's in those files can effect other things on the system.

Comment: You're right about unintended side effects. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually in the default Apache configuration file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`).

Uncomment the line:

`#ServerName example.com` and add your server's FQDN (fully qualified domain name).

Finally, run `sudo service apache2 reload` to have Apache pickup on the config file change.